# Can you use Bayes' rule twice?

Tags: probability, classification

I'm trying to build a classifier, to model the likelihood of an event C, that depends on two other events, X and Y.  I know that one can use Bayesian analysis if you have $P(X|C)$ and $P(Y|C)$  However, in my case it is easier to measure $P(C|X)$ and $P(C|Y)$. I played with Bayes' theorem, and got a result, but not sure how valid it is.

Bayes:

$$
P(C|X,Y)=\frac{P(X,Y|C)P(C)}{P(X,Y)}
$$

We assume X and Y are independent

$$
=\frac{P(X|C)P(Y|C)P(C)}{P(X)P(Y)}
$$
Subsitute Bayes for $P(X|C)$ and $P(Y|C)$

$$
=\frac{\frac{P(C|X)Pr(X)}{P(C)}\frac{P(C|Y)P(Y)}{P(C)}P(C)}{P(X)P(Y)}
$$

Eliminate:

$$
=\frac{P(C|X)P(C|Y)}{Pr(C)}
$$

Is this valid?  I know the independence assumption is dangerous, but is this at least as valid as a naive Bayesian classifier?

Comment: Your assumption was not only that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but also that they are conditionally independent given $C$. Those are very different and neither implies the other.

Comment: @DouglasZare I understand that.  But a naive bayesian classifier makes the same assumption, right?

Comment: I don't think the naive Bayesian classifier assumes independence, only conditional independence.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're reaching for is the idea that if 
$$
P(X,Y\mid C) = P(X\mid C) P(Y\mid C)
$$ 
then you could get 
$P(C\mid X,Y)$ directly, or by first computing $P(C\mid X)$ and then using that it as a prior, as in
$$
P(C\mid X,Y) = \frac{P(Y\mid C,X) P(C\mid X)}{\sum^C P(Y\mid C,X) P(C\mid X)} = \frac{P(Y\mid C) P(C\mid X)}{ \sum^C P(Y\mid C) P(C\mid X)}
$$
where $P(Y\mid C,X)=P(Y\mid C)$ follows because $X$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ given $C$ i.e. the conditional independence assumption stated first.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and perhaps I show my ignorance here. But I don't really understand the why/how. If it's ok to use $P(C|X)$ as a prior, wouldn't it be just as valid to use $P(C|Y)$ as a prior?  And aren't those completely different results?

Comment: Take that back...dug into it and looks valid.  However, I noticed that computing 
$$\frac{\frac{P(C|X)P(C|Y)}{P(C)}}{\Sigma^C \frac{P(C|X)P(C|Y)}{P(C)}}$$ 
produces the same result, as long as you're using MLE's for the input parameters.

Comment: You could have used $P(C\mid Y)$ as the prior, had $Y$ turned up before $X$.  For Bayes you can meet the data in any order or all at once; you'll always end up with the same conclusion.